# Visual Studio Debug causes SQL Server (x64) high CPU usage

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016

I have a solution with a service project. Every time I run and debbug this project, "SQL Server Windows NT - 64 bit" process jumps to 20% > CPU usage. All queries are slow, no exceptions. Same query that runs in ms, now runs in 5~10 seconds. About 10 to 20 minutes later, queries return to normal time (but sometimes not).

And I got this message on event viewer:

> A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 3607 seconds. Working set (KB): 57904, committed (KB): 207472, memory utilization: 27%%.

This problem doesn't happen when I run Console projects.

All project are .NET Framework 4.6.1, Any CPU.

My specs:

- Windows 10 Pro (I've been used 8.1, same problem)
- I5-5200U @2.2GHz
- 8 GB ram
- VS 2017 pro (I've been used 2015, same problem)
- SQL Server 2016 (SP1) 13.0.4001.0 (X64) Developer Edition

I tried this:

https://mssqlwiki.com/2012/06/27/a-significant-part-of-sql-server-process-memory-has-been-paged-out/

And this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918483/how-to-reduce-paging-of-buffer-pool-memory-in-the-64-bit-version-of-sq

But without success

Comment: [analyze the CPU usage with WPRUI/WPA, expand the stack of the sql server .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44137653/1466046) to see what SQL server is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are out of memory and SQL Server is having to move data in and out of memory excessively.

> 8 GB ram

Not much for a development system when you are running a full IDE and full database server locally.

> This problem doesn't happen when I run Console projects.

When you run console projects there is no debugger running with its demand for memory.

PS. I often see that on this system with 16GB RAM which, given RAM prices, isn't exactly generous.

Comment: I'll talk to my boss about buy more RAM. Thank you.