# vs_buildtools installer 100% CPU

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsinstaller

I attempted to update Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 and whenever the installer runs it runs at 100% cpu and takes an immense amount of time to work, if it all.

What I've tried:

- Uninstalling the installer and visual studio 2017
- Cleaning the install and rerunning it with the clean utility
- Trying to run it in --quiet mode with my chosen packages
  stopping my CI server and Octopus deploy

On any other machine it works quickly but on my build server it kills the cpu.

Comment: How long did you wait, i.e. does the installer ever finish? (and what is your actual question?)

Comment: use [WPRUI.exe/WPA.exe which is part of Windows Performance Toolkit to analyze the CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44137653/1466046)

Comment: @stijn my question is how to fix it. I waited about 5 hours the first time I encountered it. The installer carries on very slowly but inevitably doesn't finish. On my last attempt I waited 20 minutes and it didn't move past 0%.

Comment: again, analyze what the installer is doing to get a starting point on how to fix it

Comment: Def not an issue of letting the installer take the time it needs. I have been installing and updating my VS for years. Today, updating a minor VS update, the installer is creeping slow with 100% CPU, effectively blocking me to use my laptop for 4 straight hours. I can't force end it as it might mess up my work setup. (i7, 16GB  RAM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the CPU priority of `vs_installershell.exe` to `idle` caused it to start working correctly.

Comment: Installer seems to be spawning vs_installershell.exe (at least twice in my case) so if you see it stuck again, just check if the priority isn't back to normal and set it to "below normal" again.

Comment: same issue, doesnt help in my case