# Visual Studio 2017: Nasty lag in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 coupled with ReSharper 2017.2.

Quite recently (1-2 months) I started to notice an unpleasant slowness when interacting with Solution Explorer. There is a noticable lag when I hover/click elements. And scrolling is quite jerky.

There are no such issues with other windows: editor/main panel work as they should.

Maybe there is some problem with a recent update? Or may some software cause such unusual slowness? Maybe some hard drive issues? But I don't seem to have any.

EDIT: Disabling ReSharper doesn't help. Also, scrolling the Solution Explorer causes up to 40% CPU load on MacBook Pro 2013.

EDIT 2: I don't have Telerik extension as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484534/visual-studio-cpu-high-usage). And I noted that reducing the number of entries (collapsing folders) reduces slowness. Here's my report from WPA.

[image]

Comment: Is it still there if you disable ReSharper?

Comment: @cholewa1992 thanks for a suggestion! It didn't help

Comment: [analyze CPU of devenv.exe usage with WPRUI/WPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44137653/1466046)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio CPU High Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484534/visual-studio-cpu-high-usage)

Comment: expand the MainLoop entry inWPA until you see the more detailed callstack