# Visual Studio 2019 devenv CPU spike when typing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Whenever I start typing is VS2019, the `devenv` process spikes up to 13%-30%. When I stop typing, it goes down to 0.

I'm constantly hearing ***waaaaaaaaaaahhhHHHHHHHHH*** from my fans kicking on. All day. Every day. It's chipping away at my sanity. Please help.

I disabled all my extensions. I went through `Tools > Options` and disabled a bunch of things - too many to individually list - with no luck. I don't have any source control enabled. It's not indexing files.

How can I type without `devenv` thinking it needs to use 13%+ processor for every keystroke? I'm hoping someone has a "magic bullet" setting I can adjust to make this stop.

**Update 9/13/2019**

Here's a trace, although I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

**Update 10/11/2019**

Trace updated with symbols loaded, and ntdll.dll and mscorlib.ni.dll nodes expanded.

[image]

Comment: [capture a trace of the cpu usage with Windows Performance Recorder and analyze it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44137653/1466046)

Comment: have you analyzed the cpu usage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio CPU High Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484534/visual-studio-cpu-high-usage)

Comment: @magicandre1981: I updated the OP with a trace. Can you help me understand what I should be looking for?

Comment: you need to load the debug symbols and expand the first ntdll.dll entry and the 2nd mscor dll entry, they use most cpu

Comment: @magicandre1981: I re-uploaded the trace, this time with symbols loaded and the two nodes you mentioned expanded. I'm still lost though. What should I be looking for as a sign of a problem?

Comment: PDBs are not resolved correctly. in symbol option make sure the **Filename.etl.ngenpdb** folder is checked.

Comment: if you still need help, share the ETL + Filename.etl.ngenpdb folder via OneDrive share link as zip/7z. I'll take a look