# VBCS Compiler takes almost 70 % of CPU on first run of every page of published website with EF in ASP .Net MVC on live server

Tags: entity-framework, roslyn

Taking too much time and too much CPU
[Image is attached for more information]

[image]

Comment: [capture a trace of the cpu usage with Windows Performance Recorder and analyze it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44137653/1466046). The sample is Visual Studio, but the tools work for all other programs

Comment: have you installed the WPT on the server and captured a trace of the publishing?